# Spring:Unable to read @property into config.xml

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

we have old application which uses web.xml.Recently we started having trouble where our app reading properties into config.xml where we have defined as below.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd


    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd">

     <context:component-scan base-package="com.abc.xyz"/>
  
 <bean id="abcService"
          class="org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean">
        <property name="serviceInterface"
                  value="com.abc.xyz.service.ServicesWS"/>
        <property name="wsdlDocumentUrl" value="classpath:/abc.wsdl"/>
        <property name="namespaceUri" value="http://abc.zyz.com/"/>
        <property name="serviceName" value="ABCServices"/>
        <property name="url"
                  value="${endpoint.address}"/>
        <property name="handlerResolver" ref="LogResolver"/>
      
    </bean>
  

</beans>
```

However If pass `endpoint.address` in value field it is working fine.
Am I doing anything wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify **propertyplaceholder** (or specify the property reference  `<context:property-placeholder properties-ref="customPropertyFactory" />` if any). To specify the placeholder use:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
  <property name="location">
    <value>application.properties</value>
  </property>
</bean>
```

This would be added to the config.xml mentioned here. Also, please do share the recent changes to your application context in case it stopped working after some change.